# Visual Studio 2005 .vcproj files won't stay encoded as UTF-8

Tags: unicode, visual-studio-2005

The problem: I edit a .vcproj file, save it as UTF-8 (and specify that in the xml header), and when I open it in VS, the next time it saves it the encoding reverts back to CP-1255/1252/1251 (depending on the Localized Settings on the machine).

This has become a problem in our R&D, since whenever someone commits a .vcproj file the encoding changes according to their machine's configuration. How can I configure VS to just use UTF-8 and stop this back and forth ANSI encoding dance?

Comment: ok, so more sensible questions is, what is the impact? are the project files are getting changed when loaded therefore people are checking them in when there is no change? or does the re-encoding break the reading of the project for others? or is it really just a problem of more changes than expected and therefore making more noise when reviewing diff's etc?

Comment: The problem is superfluous commits, which translate into superfluous reloading of projects upon update. a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cheap answer: make all dev pc's have same Localized Settings.

Comment: some people speak different languages.. not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try adding the BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to your files. I know of [one program which can do it for you](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/), it's actually just 3 bytes at the beginning of your files. Go into the "Format" menu and try the different UTF-8 options.

Comment: I know this is an old, maybe even ancient answer, but a byte order mark is illegal in XML files (which a .vcproj file is), as well as using a different encoding from what is specified in the XML header. Software reading such files can and often will produce errors and/or refuse to read the files entirely.